# Json Deserializing, graph api

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to access the facebook user information(education, hometown details) using graph api
Is it possible to do this  string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,picture,bio,quotes,education,hometown&access_token=" + oAuth.Token;

```
 string json = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);
 UserInfo ui = js.Deserialize<UserInfo>(json);

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb = sb.Append("Name : " + ui.name + "<br/>");
sb = sb.Append("<Img src='" + ui.picture + "' alt='' />");
sb = sb.Append("Bio : " + ui.bio + "<br/>");
sb = sb.Append("Quotes : " + ui.quotes + "<br/>");
//This does not work      sb = sb.Append("hometown : " + ui.hometown[0] + "<br/>");
//This does not work      sb = sb.Append("Education : " + ui.education[0] + "<br/>");
```

I the following UserInfo class

```
public class UserInfo
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string picture { get; set; }
        public string bio { get; set; }
        public string quotes { get; set; }
        public HometownInfo from { get; set; }

    }
    public class HometownInfo
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Please give me some inputs.. I dont have a lot of experience in .net. Also, I understand that ui.hometown[0] is not the correct way to access the user Hometown info... 
Please correct me
Thanks
SC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FacebookUser
{
    public string    id { get; set; }
    public string  name { get; set; }
    public string about { get; set; }

    public string link { get; set; }
    public hometown hometown = new hometown();
}

public class hometown
{
   public string   id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
}
```